# How to handle an entered number in another activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

In Activity1 I use an editText (Number-Decimal) and a button. After the decimal number was set in editText, I use the button to switch Activity1 with Activity2. In Activity2 I need to use this decimal number, how can I do that?

I use this in Activity2 but is not working.

```
var selectedNumber = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
selectedNumber.setText("Your number is" + editText);
```

The result is "Your number is null".

Comment: you make an intent and put your string in extra then capture the intent in your Activity2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you make an intent and put your string in extra then capture the intent in your Activity2

In your make Activity1 create intent with extra.

```
val your_number = your_edittext.text.toString()
val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Activity2::class.java)
intent.putExtra("number", your_number)
startActivity(intent)
```

In your Activity2 capture the extra intent

```
val openIntent = intent
val number = openIntent.getStringExtra("number")
```

Comment: I have another problem now, in Activity1 I use a button like this: 
button7.setOnClickListener { _: View? ->
            val Intent = Intent(baseContext, Activity2::class.java)
            startActivity(Intent);
I change the Intent name  in Intent2 but in Activity2 I can't link this when I type Intent2 "Unresolved reference: Intent2".

Comment: the `intent` in `val openIntent = intent` is standard and cannot be changed.